# Pass a regular CURSOR to a PL/SQL procedure that expects SYS_REFCURSOR

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, sys-refcursor

I have a lot of named cursors in PL/SQL like this:

```
cursor MY_CURSOR_01 is select * from my_table_01;
cursor MY_CURSOR_02 is select * from my_table_02;
```

I want to use them in `dbms_xmlgen.newContext` procedure which expects a `SYS_REFCURSOR` or a `VARCHAR2` containing the actual query.

I already know that I could do:

```
dbms_xmlgen.newContect('select * from my_table_01');
```

But I would like to reuse the existing cursors I have, without rewriting them as string queries.

Any ideas? I am on Oracle 10gR2.

Comment: Not so far as I know, but there might be something buried in some `DBMS_whatever` package that can do this. You might try posting this on [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:1:0) - and if you get a response please link to that from here (either as a comment or an answer). Thanks.

Comment: I doubt that there are any packages that handle this kind of conversion, because `cursor` is not a datatype. How would the parameters of such a function/procedure be defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think such a function exists, because Oracle's language specification doesn't allow for `cursor` objects to be passed as parameters. Unless Oracle has used some magic somewhere, there's just no way to generically reference a `cursor` without using a `refcursor`.

However, you don't need to embed your SQL in a string to use a `sys_refcursor`. Here's a very simple example showing that a `sys_refcursor` can be opened using static SQL:

```
DECLARE
   c SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   OPEN c FOR SELECT * FROM DUAL;
   CLOSE c;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks Allan. I was aware of that possibility. But I wanted to ask if what I was wanting is possible. Thanks again.